# How to display physical dimension fields on node--product.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module and I want to print the physical dimension fields(machine name: field_width) value on product detail page.

How can I print physical dimension fields value in `node--product.tpl.php` file?

My file code is like so:

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"
<?php print $attributes; ?> >

<?php print $user_picture; ?>

<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
<span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>



<div class="c-i-rgt">


<div class="zomer_img">
<?php
if ($view_mode == 'teaser')
else
print render($content['field_image1']); 
print render($content['field_width']);
print render($content['product:commerce_price']);
?>
</div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the field to be displayed under display settings for the content type?

[image: Drupal display settings]

Above is how the Field UI looks, maybe your product dimension field is hidden?

There is a [guide here](http://drupalwatchdog.com/1/1/building-commerce-product-display), on how to customize the Drupal commerce product display.

If you want to print the field in node--product.tpl.php you should first drag it so it is visible in the field UI.

Then you need to add `render($content['product:field_width']);`

Comment: thanks for reply but i want this thing by writing code in node--product.tpl.php. Can you tell me how we can access these fields using codes...

Comment: ya sure..just 1 mnt..

Comment: Ya i added this in my file but it is not show anything..

Comment: type of field_width is a physical dimension.. and it is a field of product type content in drupal commerce ..

Comment: yes field is in UI first ..yes this field have value.. width, height, lenght & unit..

Comment: I provide you the backend of content type..just 1 mnt..

Comment: render($content['product:field_width']); it is also not working..

Comment: i got error when i try to post image "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: My field type is physical dimensions..in store=>product=>manage field.& i make a content type product in structure=>content type.& i refer store product type in structure product type for node display in drupal commerce..Can you please tell me that how i can access this field..

Comment: Try installing the module Devel and put this in your tpl file dpm($content); Then you can debug and see where in the array your value is. I know too little about Drupal Commerce to say exactly the correct code.